# Как правильно работать с форматом HL7 в рамках .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, стандарт

Поступило предложение для программы обменна данными в рамках медицинском микро компании, одним из правил есть работа с HL7, но больше никакой конкретики. От заказа я не отказался, т.к. система не является очень сложной, но столкнулся с проблемой понимания этого HL7.

Понятное дело, что я с ноги влетел в интернет, что бы обучиться новым знаниям в сфере, с которой не так уж и много работал, но я обнаружил... Ничего ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Что такое HL7 v3? Что некий медицинский цифровой формат для данных, который начал разрабатываться в 1998 году и выпустился в 2005 году (Вроде бы как). И ещё очень много другой воды, но я не нашёл ничего, что хоть как-то объясняло как с ним работать. Вообще ничего конкретного, тем более, для .NET. То ли это какой-то протокол, то ли это какой-то сервер, или это просто стандарт для оформления классов в моей программе, ограничение надёжности передачи информации.

Может кто-то имел дело, объясните пожалуйста, что к чему и как с этим работать, или может я что-то прям упустил.

Что говорит GPT по этому поводу. Есть библиотека NHapi которая вроде бы как порт Hapi с Java, но в интернете лучше вообще не гуглить Hapi, потому что, как оказывается это протокол... Который продают за деньги...

В общем, остро нуждаюсь в объяснении

Comment: Видать, с поиском что-то не задалось.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HL7 Standards](https://www.hl7.org/index.cfm?ref=nav)

[HL7 Messages Examples – Complete Guide 2023](https://digitalhealth.folio3.com/blog/hl7-messages-examples/)

[v2 Sample Messages](https://confluence.hl7.org/display/OO/v2+Sample+Messages) там даже ссылка на какой-то github.

[Getting Sample HL7 Data](https://help.interfaceware.com/getting-sample-hl7-data.html)

И вишенка на торте [HL7-dotnetcore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HL7-dotnetcore)!

Нет, ну прямо руки чешутся:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У самого такое бывает: создаёшь, вроде бы, вполне нормальный запрос, а в результате - фиг. А потом подумаешь, и находятся ответы.

Comment: Спасибо, у меня реально ничего подобного в поиске не было. На Github нет того, что я ищу, но ссылки полезные, которые мне не встречались ранее. Спасибо

Comment: Да, удачи! Я сам тоже люблю браться за подобные задачи.